# Eclipse CDT Linuxtools gives broken pipe error

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am running Eclipse CDT 6.0.2 on a SLES 11 x86_64 platform.
My project is of linuxtools type.
I am getting the following error running builds:

> "
>   ../libtool: line 747: echo: write error: Broken pipe
>   make[2]: write error
>   make[1]: *** [all recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: write error
>   make: *** [all recursive] Error 1
>   "

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A "broken pipe" means that a program was receiving a piped data stream and then suddenly exited. The system will send a `SIGPIPE` to the process that was inputting data to the stream, telling it, essentially, "Okay, the recipient died unexpectedly. You can stop sending it data."

I've compiled many a program that had pre-packaged versions of files from autotools such as "config.guess," "ltmain.sh," "missing," etc. A lot of times (especially on my x86_64 installation) these files were old and improperly suited to deal with a 64-bit compilation environment. I believe this script may be needing to be updated.

Try running:

```
$ automake --add-missing --copy --force
```